# maps working with debug API key but not with release API key...?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have finished the development of my app which uses Google Maps. During the development/debug phase, I used a debug MD5 key and generated a debug Google Maps API key on Google website. Google Maps worked perfectly well on both emulator and device.

Now, I want to release my app. I generated a release MD5 key and a release Google Maps API key.

I copied/pasted this release API key in my xml map file:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    [...]
    android:apiKey="xxxxxxx"
/>
```

But now, when I run the app on my device, I just get a gray grid instead of a map...

I took care to put android:debuggable to false in my manifest:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
                    android:label="@string/app_name"
                    android:debuggable="false"
                    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

Do you know what I can do to solve my issue ?

Thanks !!!

[EDIT] Perhaps the problem is due to the fact that I run the app on my device in debug mode and not in release mode ? If it is the issue, how to run my app in release mode on my device ?

Comment: did you signed the application with your release certificate? the one link to the maps api key?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know how to sign my app with my release certificate to create the apk file (I do it with "Export") but how to run a "release signed app" to check that it works properly ? Thanks !!

Comment: use adb to install the apk on your device/emulator (adb install app.apk). Don't forget to uninstall the debug version first, otherwise the signature difference will prevent the installation

Comment: Thanks !! I launched my app with adb install app.apk and the map is displayed properly ! Very helpful. Many thanks :)

Comment: Just in case anybody cares: I had same problem, and I had to `Export Android Application` from Eclipse, first of all(as you do when sign an app for GooglePlay), to make the `MapView` work with release API Key. If you just click `Run As - > Android Application` as you do when test an app, the `MapView` wouldn't load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [njzk2's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257353/android-google-maps-api-maps-working-with-debug-api-key-but-not-with-release/9854991#comment8733900_7257353):

> use adb to install the apk on your device/emulator (adb install app.apk). Don't forget to uninstall the debug version first, otherwise the signature difference will prevent the installation

Comment: Thanks for highlighting njzk2's comment, otherwise I would have missed his miracle suggestion.